# Drag/drop and resize using material design

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, material-design, draggable, angular-dragdrop

I am creating a web app using angular and Material, I want to be able to drag, drop and resize my sections. I have seen many plugins, e.g. [angular-gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster) and [gridstack-angular](http://kdietrich.github.io/gridstack-angular/demo/#) but did not get right solution.